# Why does fine sandpaper cause more friction than coarse sandpaper?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

I found that if you drag a wooden block across a piece of 150 grit sandpaper, there is more friction than if you do the same with a piece of 50 grit sandpaper. Why is this? I tried to find an answer on the Internet, but they were not specific enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: finer grade sandpaper has more points of physical contact than rougher grade sandpaper, and each point of contact is a source of friction.

Answer (score -2):

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-do-flies-and-other-in/

Extrapolate from there and see how it would apply to 150 grit sandpaper compared with 50 grit.

Comment: @ dlb I think not.